# Image displays in .HTML but not .PHP

Tags: php, html, css, image

I was working on a website and after finishing up the styling I wanted to start with the server-side. At first it was "index.html" and then the extension was changed to "index.php".

I loaded up XAMPP and went to run the website and one of the images failed to display. The image is actually a background image of a DIV (Bootstrap Jumbotron). I then changed the file extension back to .html and the image displays successfully. Then again back to .php and the image fails to display.

I then attempted to use a different image from the same folder (while the extension is .php), and it actually works. All other images work except this one image that fails to display.

Here is the CSS for the background image:

```
 /* Does not work */
.jumbotron_image
{
    background-image: url('../Images/lonely%20android.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Works successfully with a different image */
.jumbotron_image
{
    background-image: url('../Images/normal%20android.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is really weird and I have no idea what is causing it. I am thinking the fault lies with the image itself since all other images work. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Don't use spaces in filenames!!!

Comment: I tried that. I named the image I want to "image.jpg" and it still didn't work. And also the other image that works in the example has spaces.

Comment: I didn't mean that as a solution, just a general comment. If you want to make your filenames a bit more readable then use underscores or hyphens.

Comment: Define "does not work".  Is an HTTP request made for the image?  What is the address of that request?  What is the server's response?

Comment: it has nothing to do with php. except if it is related to your cache, in which case going back to html wont work. probably it's all about file reading permissions. have you download the image from internet? have you check access permissions?

Comment: Check your browser console see what it says about the image URL. It will show whether you have a perms prob or the file isn't where its supposed to be